# cannot understand the exact different between the INT and INTEGER from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is my first query for creating the customer database:

```
create table customers (id int PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar(50));
```

and I want add foreign key for the other order table so I create 2nd database Order

```
create table myOrder 
(
     order_ID int, 
     order_date date, 
     customers_ID int, 

     Foreign Key (customers_id) REFERENCES customers(id)
);
```

My order query is not working but when I replace `INT` with `INTEGER`, then query works fine, but I can't understand that the exact difference is.

Comment: What error message do you see when determining it "not working"

Answer (score 2):

Integer  or INT are synonymous..

from mysql DOC https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

> MySQL supports the SQL standard integer types INTEGER (or INT)